# Use sign-in option on excel Ribbon by Manifest.xml file

Tags: reactjs, office365, ms-office, manifest, office-js

How can I use sign-in features on excel ribbon. So that after successfully sign-in all buttons on ribbon will change according to our requirements.
Is it possible with Manifest.xml file or do I need to use some another mechanism?
I am using React.js for creating taskpane on right-side of excel. This taskpane is opened after clicked on ribbon button and this ribbon button is coming after addin the manifest file to insert addin option.

[Attaching this Pic for step by step process, Which I need in Excel Ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKiKR.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "all buttons on ribbon will change according to our requirmentments"?

Comment: Hiding buttons on ribbon menu in manifest file after successful sigin is not possible. You can add all your custom logic to hide /show button in Task pane but not on the Ribbon menu. Anyway @RickKirkham is here to advise rather than me

Comment: If show/hide is what you meant by "buttons on ribbon will change", then @RagavanRajan is correct. You cannot currently show/hide custom buttons with an add-in. Microsoft is working on adding that feature to the add-in platform in the future.

Comment: @RickKirkham. Cool. Thanks for the confirmation. It is really a great news and will be definitely cool feature. Have a great day!!

Comment: My question is after adding the manifest file ribbon will appear where only sign-in button will be there. After successfully sign in user can able to see different buttons on ribbon (including sign out button). After sign out again user will see only the sign-in button.

Comment: @RickKirkham, kindly check the screenshot, I have attached to that link. and please guide me to create that functionality on ribbon.

Comment: @BarakJob What you want to do in your screenshot cannot be done at this time with Office Web Add-ins. The enabled/disabled status of buttons cannot be changed at run time and the names of buttons cannot be changed at runtime. Microsoft is working on adding that feature.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do in your screenshot cannot be done at this time with Office Web Add-ins. The enabled/disabled status of buttons cannot be changed at run time and the names of buttons cannot be changed at runtime. Microsoft is working on adding that feature.